# Boss is not invited to project meeting set up by boss’s boss

Tags: professionalism, politics

I have a boss (Jane) and her boss (Mark) invited me to a meeting on a new project.

I don’t know if this is the norm because Mark is new. I want Jane's support and this might be detrimental to relationship with Jane as it will seem like a ‘going over his/her head’ because Mark is dealing straight with me. Other people on the invite seem like direct players on the project.

How to handle it professionally? Jane asked about meeting, should I forward invite without getting on bad side of Mark?

Comment: I'd recommend assigning fake names to your boss and their boss in your question because as it stands it's a chore to read and somewhat hard to keep track of who's done what.

Comment: i added aliases to clear up the Q, please feel free to edit as necessary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not your problem, you are not the organizer of the meeting.

If your boss asks about it, just tell them to truth. That you got invited and what the agenda is (if there is one). Forward the invite only if they ask you to do so.

Otherwise just go to the meeting and see what happens. If you feel it's important for your boss to be in the loop, sent them the meeting notes and/or mention it in your 1:1 meetings

Comment: It’s worth noting this may very well be your boss delegating the work on you. “Yeah, I cant make it mark but please invite SouthernBell will you?

Comment: Treat your boss following the principle of minimum surprise. Say to her, "Mark invited me to blahblah meeting; do you have any advice for me about how best to represent our group's interests at that meeting?"  Then Jane knows what's going on. If she believes she needs to be present, she can work it out with her boss. And you won't appear the slightest bit disloyal to her.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that there is a reason why the bosses boss didn't invite your boss. (It might be an oversight, in which case you just watch how it plays out. If you go to the meeting and your bosses boss asks where boss is, you know it was an oversight. We ignore this possibility).

Do you want to take sides with your boss against your bosses boss? That's a risky thing to do. I'd keep out of it and not volunteer anything. If you are asked questions, answer them truthfully.

Answer (score 1):

> How would you handle it? Boss asked about meeting, should I forward
>   invite without getting on bad side of Boss’s boss?

Assuming that this wasn't an oversight:

Scenario #1

If your boss only asked about the meeting, then you tell him about the meeting and any detail he wants to know. Forwarding him the invite, when he didn't specifically ask for the invite, is just asking for trouble.

Scenario #2

If you trust your boss implicitly, you can do anything you like. But I really doubt you would be here asking this question if you thought this was the case.

Scenario #3

If mommy and daddy are fighting, it's best to just forward the email and preface it with "Here is the info you requested." or "Here is the invite you requested."